# Unable to open AVI file

Tags: avi

I am unable to open a 114,808KB AVI file using VLC.
I can open smaller AVI from the same thumb drive.
Any suggestions, ideas, thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried to copy the file to your computer and play it from there? that will give you an idea if the file is corrupted (not playable from anywhere) or it just cannot be played from the thumbdrive, which is weird.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to open"? Do you get a error message? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/894707/edit) and add the error message so we can help you.

Comment: The security folks copied four time segments (files) of video from two security cameras onto a thumb drive.  All are AVI files.  Three open so that we can view them.  One file does not open.  No error message.  Nothing happens at all.  Very strange.  Have not encountered this previously.  I transferred the files onto three different computers.  Same results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For copyright reasons, Ubuntu can not package all media formats in every installation.  If it is legal in your area, you can follow the directions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

There is a legal alternative to the restricted extras package if there are copyright laws in your area that apply, it is fluendo.  http://www.fluendo.com/en/oneplay/  As of today, March 19, 2017, the codecs are 25 Euro get the legal package.

If the file is copied from a dvd, looking for libdvdcss2 might help. I can't post more than two links since I am new, or I would link that too.  Another thing to check is whether Digital Rights Management is involved.

Comment: Thanks but I believe it is a different problem because I am able to open and view three other video clips copied from the same source from the same thumb drive.  S

Answer (score 0):

Download SMPlayer!  AVIs (audio video interleave) on QuickTime are no longer supported by Apple but play on SMPlayer in Ubuntu!!